# Нужно ли ставить предлог "в" перед числами?

Tags: синтаксис, предлоги, числительные

Например, как правильно "результат в 82 балла" или "результат 82 балла"? "Штраф в 80 тысяч" или "штраф 80 тысяч" и так далее. Буду признателен за ответ с правилом из какого-нибудь справочника :)

Comment: Приведите полное предложение. Вне контекста можно предложить, например, поставить тире: штраф — 80 тысяч.

Comment: Например, "Загитова показала результат 82,92 балла" или "Загитова показала результат в 82,92 балла"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Загитова показала результат 82,92 балла" или "Загитова показала результат в 82,92 балла"?

Корректно: **Загитова показала результат 82,92 балла.**

Примеры из Нацкоруса:

> А через три года, в 2018-м, объем рынка уже превысит докризисный уровень и покажет **результат 2,33 млн автомобилей**. [Алексей Грамматчиков. Залечь на дно // «Эксперт», 2015]
>
> На четвертое место, по данным Box Office Mojo, поднялся «Форсаж-7» **с результатом 1511 млн долларов**. [Вячеслав Суриков. Культура // «Эксперт», 2015]
>
> Доля людей за 60 сегодня колеблется от 1% в ОАЭ до 32% в Японии (в 2050 году Япония будет лидировать **с результатом 41%**). [Дмитрий Ермольцев. Стареем // «Русский репортер», 2013]

Примеров типа "результат в ... единиц" в Нацкорпусе не обнаружено.

Дополнение.

Вот что удалось найти в авторитетном издании (Русская грамматика. Академия наук СССР институт русского языка «Русская грамматика» — М.: Наука, 1980.):

> [§ 1856](https://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1773#1856). Особый вид вариативных отношений – взаимная заменяемость вводящего количественный определитель творительного падежа беспредложного существительных со знач. **размера, меры, веса, протяженности, цены** и предложно-падежных форм, а в непринужденной, но строго нормированной речи – также и формы именительного падежа в определяющей функции: канава шириной в два метра – канава в два метра и канава шириной два метра, камень весом в полпуда – камень в полпуда – камень весом полпуда, цистерна емкостью в тысячу литров – цистерна в тысячу литров и цистерна емкостью тысяча литров, дистанция протяженностью в тысячу метров – дистанция в тысячу метров – дистанция протяженностью тысяча метров – дистанция тысяча метров, стадо численностью в сто голов – стадо в сто голов и стадо численностью сто голов – стадо сто голов, волнение силой в девять баллов – силой девять баллов – волнение в девять баллов – волнение девять баллов, баржа грузоподъемностью в тысячу тонн – баржа в тысячу тонн – баржа грузоподъемностью тысяча тонн, скидка размером в двадцать процентов – скидка в двадцать процентов – на двадцать процентов – скидка двадцать процентов, дорога длиной в сто верст – дорога в сто верст – дорога длиною сто верст, карандаш ценой в две копейки – карандаш в две копейки – карандаш ценой две копейки, кухня площадью в семь метров – кухня в семь метров – кухня площадью семь метров – кухня семь метров.

В цитате говорится о существительных со значением размера, меры, веса, протяженности, цены. На мой взгляд, существительное *результат* не входит в этот список, невозможно построить логическую цепочку (как в цитате): результат размером(?!) в 82 балла -> результат в 82 балла. Поэтому мне кажется, что "результат в 82 балла" — неверно. Примеров типа "результат в ... единиц" в Нацкорпусе не обнаружено.

Comment: А других аргументов у Вас нет? Вы пытались искать примеры "с результатом в" и "штраф в"? Таких много находится в нормальных книгах. (С ответом я не согласился только потому, что он меня нисколько не убеждает. Если бы Вы хотя бы сказали, что не смогли найти цитат с предлогом "в", я не ставил бы минус. А так создаётся впечатление, что Вы искали только подтверждение собственной интуиции, а не попытались разобраться в вопросе.)

Comment: @grizzly Про штраф я  не писал, а поиск "результат в  <цифры> " в Нацкорпусе дает только *результаты в каком-то году*. Мое мнение: *в* можно ставить,  если имеется в виду "размером в" (штраф размером в 500 рублей), но к результату это не применимо.

Comment: Хорошо, я сейчас выберу цитат разного типа и дам отдельный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Я сменил "минус" на "плюс", хотя и считаю, что окончательный вывод у Вас ошибочен. Но это именно те аргументы, которые я искал.

Comment: Я сослался на Ваш ответ в своём, но сделал противоположный вывод.

Comment: @grizzly Тем интереснее будет читателю — придется самому думать и решать.

Comment: Получается, в случае с существительными со значением размера, меры, веса, протяженности и цены существуют равнозначные варианты с предлогом и без? И как я хочу в предложении, так и ворочу? :D

Comment: Да, воротите себе на здоровье.

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию, которую я использовала при ответе https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456694/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83

Answer (score 2):

Допустимы оба варианта. Вообще говоря, разрешены любые варианты словоупотребления, если они широко распространены в качественных изданиях, и при этом не запрещены правилами русского языка.

Запретов ни на один из обсуждаемых вариантов я не обнаружил, а вот примеров использования — сколько угодно. В другом ответе были приведены примеры без предлога, поэтому я дам здесь только другие примеры. Как обычно, я стараюсь опираться на добротные издания.

> Баланс движения капиталов имел положительный **результат в** 8,5 млрд. фр.
>   (Реферативный сборник: Экономика промышленности, 1977)
>
> КОА дала положительный **результат в** 18,6 % (Журнал микробиологии,
>   эпидемиологии и иммунобиологии, 1988)
>
> Реакция д-ра Максимова при технической простоте дает результат в 30—40
>   минут. (Официальный сборник Наркомздрава СССР, 1938)
>
> ...**Результат в 70** баллов шкалы может практически считаться верхней
>   границей нормальных колебаний (Вопросы психологии, 1980)
>
> И только одна девочка выполнила данное задание с **результатом в** 4,8
>   баллов. (Развитие познавательной сферы глухих учащихся, 2017)
>
> ...Что позволило закончить год **с результатом в** 4,2%. (Индустриализация
>   СССР, 1970)
>
> В прыжках в длину **с результатом в** 7,03 м, показанным в последней
>   попытке, ... (Физическая культура: Учебник для 5–7 классов, 2013)
>
> ...Удержав **штраф в** 12 др. (Организация общественного строительства в
>   Древней Греции, 2018)
>
> По такому иску «о положенном или подвешенном» (actio de positis et
>   suspensis) взыскивался **штраф в** 10 000 сестерциев. (Римское право:
>   учебник, 2009)
>
> ...Наложила на архимандрита **штраф в** 50 рублей (История России с
>   древнейших времен, Том 22, 2017)

Это только капля в море подобных цитат.

**Дополнение**.

Благодаря ответу **М_Г** теперь можно понять все приведенные цитаты.
Искать нужно в списке единиц измерения (слово, которое находится после цифр): проценты, метры, баллы и т.п. В "Русской грамматике" приведены примеры со всеми использованными в приведенных цитатах единицами: баллами, процентами, различными деньгами и метрами (см. ответ **М_Г**).

Answer (score 0):

*Ростом в два метра*, или *ростом 2 метра*? Первое — выражение не вполне математически чёткое, сродни выражению ещё менее точному «под два метра ростом». Предлоги (в, под, с, за) указывают лишь на масштабность величины, а суждение основывается на личном опыте и своём отношении к достоверности.

О правильности говорить не приходится: верно и то и другое. Но когда речь идёт о конкретных суммах в баллах или рублях, т. е. об информировании, такие «суждения» возможны, но вызывают вопросы об их уместности.