# Предлог "в" с указанием на величину

Tags: предлоги

Возможен ли предлог "в" в случах обозначения какой-либо величины, приложимой к предмету, явлению, живому существу?

Рост в 160 см.
Бумага в 300 грамм.
Фильм в 60 минут.

Comment: Здесь же был ответ... Где он?

Answer (score 1):

Употребление подобных выражений регулируется правилами, обозначенными в «Русской грамматике». https://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5315&0a0=1773#1856

Нужно построить **вариативный ряд сочетаний** с предлогом В и без предлога В, с указанием слова с количественным значением (рост, вес, размер и др.) или без этого слова.  Далее следует определить возможную область применения сочетаний из этого ряда  и их частотность.

1)  Люди ростом в 160  см – люди ростом 160  см.

2) Бумага  весом в 300 грамм – бумага  весом 300 грамм – бумага   в 300 грамм.

3) Фильм продолжительностью в 60 минут – фильм продолжительностью 60 минут – фильм в 60 минут.

Во всех приведенных примерах **второй вариант** представляется наиболее предпочтительным и частотным. **Третий вариант** имеет скорее ограниченное применение. Он в большей степени разговорный и используется в тех случаях,  когда  тема ясно обозначена.

Например:

На фильм длительностью 1 час  тратится в среднем 400 Мегабайт. А **фильм в 2 часа**  –  это сколько гигабайт?

Бумага плотностью в  300 г/м2 (А4 , 50 листов) стоит 600 рублей, а **бумага в 200 г/м2**  будет стоить меньше.

Вопрос на данную тему уже обсуждался: [Нужно ли ставить предлог "в" перед числами?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445119/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/445136#445136)