# Можно ли обойтись без предлога "в"?

Tags: предлоги

*...при общем населении страны в 83 миллиона человек.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто выкинуть предлог нельзя, потому что пропадёт связь между членами предложения.

БТС Кузнецова:

> 6. кого-что, ком-чём. Указывает на количество, размер, расстояние, состав, меру и т.п. чего-л. Мороз в тридцать градусов. Весом в сто
>      килограммов. Стоимостью в две тысячи. В двух шагах от метро. Отряд в
>      сто человек.

Можно заменить на другие конструкции:

- при 83-миллионном населении;
- при том, что население составляет 83 млн человек.

Answer (score 2):

**Грамота.ру считает, что без предлога В можно обойтись.**

Кроме того, вопрос уже два раза обсуждался на форуме, в частности там приведена информация из Грамматики-80.

Вопрос № 273128

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, корректный вариант: **"с интервалом в 30 минут" ЛИБО "с интервалом 30 минут".**
Обновление списков выполняется сервером автоматически с интервалом в 30 минут.
Благодарю!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Корректно: **с интервалом 30 минут** (ср. с аналогичными конструкциями без предлога "в": тиражом 5 тысяч экземпляров, глубиной 20 метров и т. п.) Но при этом: раз в тридцать минут, раз в час и т. п.

Конкретно по этой теме встречаются **оба варианта**, в том числе **без предлога В:**

Представлен список 10 самых населенных стран мира. Китай - самая большая страна мира **с населением 1 400 970 200 человек**... http://www.statdata.ru/10-samih-bolshih-stran-mira-po-naseleniu

Другой пример:  *Это большой пласт самобытной культуры с населением **более 180 млн человек***  В этом случае предлог В вообще не подходит.

[Нужно ли ставить предлог "в" перед числами?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445119/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

[Предлог "в" с указанием на величину](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456694/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Comment: Слово "страны" как бы разрывает связь между мерой и числом. Увидеть бы такие примеры без В...